# How to make my image be recognized by IDLE python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I made a background.gif through GIMP app. I saved it as "gif" extension but cannot see any option in GIMP for making it as gif in that program. Even worse, I just click something that "looks" the same as the tutorial does.

I see in the tutorial that background must have a gif extension. When I run my gif in IDLE python, it says my background can't be recognized. Is there something wrong with my backround.gif on the GIMP app, or my code? My code and the tutorial code seem to be the sameare same.

This is the error i got:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Stickman\stickmangame.py", line 35, in 
> g = Game()
> File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Stickman\stickmangame.py", line 16, in **init**
> self.bg = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
> File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 3545, in **init**
> Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
> File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 3501, in **init**
> self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "background.gif"

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title("Mr. Stick Man Races For The Exit")
        self.tk.resizable(0,0)
        self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500, height=500, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tk.update()
        self.canvas_height = 500
        self.canvas_width = 500
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
        w = self.bg.width()
        h = self.bg.height()
        for x in range(0, 5):
            for y in range(0, 5):
                self.canvas.create_image(x * w, y * h, image=self.bg, anchor='nw')
        self.sprites = []
        self.running = True

    def mainloop(self):
        while 1:
            if self.running == True:
                for sprite in self.sprites:
                    sprite.move()
            self.tk.update_idletasks()
            self.tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)


g = Game()
g.mainloop()
```

All  of them are same as the tutorial code. I chekced it many times.

I expect the Canvas will show my background.gif.

This is the option Ii found in my GIMP app:
[gimp extension available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgqhz.jpg)

And then i just click the GIMP XCF Image. And show all files. and save it. If not like that i can't save it as GIF extenstion

Comment: Can you please share your backgroud.gif also?

Comment: Nah, i couln't upload it . it says "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported". here

Comment: check if file has really GIF format, not only extension. Or use `pillow.ImageTk` to load png, jpg in tkinter - read: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).

Comment: GIMP saves in own format `xcf` and you have to use function `File > Export ` to save it as `png`, `jpg`, `gif`, etc.

Comment: Seems your image is not a gif one, can you please try to run your code with a different gif image? try with a simplest one you can find from the internet

Comment: Thank you very much. it solved now. i must save it through File > Export and it saves a gif now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be just as a PNG file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).